# Нужно вычесть из следующего массива предыдущий Python

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
for Elem in ElemList:
        print("Processing...")
        ElemTurn = int(Elem.get('turn'))
        ElemTime = int(Elem.get('time'))
        print('Ход', ElemTurn)
        print('Время', ElemTime)
```

вывод:

```
Ход 1
Время 13446500
Processing...
Ход 2
Время 13446507
Processing...
Ход 3
Время 13446510
```

Process finished with exit code 0
Как к примеру из времени Хода 2, вычесть время Хода 1, из времени Хода 3 вычесть время Хода 2 и т.д и вывести это?

Answer (score 0):

```
LastTurn = 0

for Elem in ElemList:
  ...
  ElemTurn = int(Elem.get('turn'))
  print(ElemTurn - LastTurn)
  LastTurn = ElemTurn
  ...
```